# Catch "signal" in routing page

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have create a socket in app.js

**APP.JS**

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.set('socketio', io);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connesso');
    socket.on('message', function(data){
        console.log("Oo");
    })
})
```

In my html page I have a js script

```html
newex.onsubmit = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('message', {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value, 
    desc: document.getElementById('description').value
  });
}
```

So, when an user submit a form, the socket should send a "signal", but I want catch the signal in a routing page, not in my app.js
I tried with:

**ROUTING PAGE**

```
io = req.app.get('socketio');
io.on('message', function(message){
  console.log(message);
})
```

But it doesn't work! I get that I need to put io.on(...) into io.sockets.on clousure but I don't get why. Can you explain me mechanism of socket.io?

**EDIT**
I set 'socket' in this way and I try code of tbking but it doesn't work anyway

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Connesso');
  app.set('socket', socket);
  //socket.on('message', function(message){console.log("Ricevuto")})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the messages from the specific socket the client is connected to.

Try this in your routing file:

```
var socket = req._socket;
socket.on('message', function(message){
    console.log(message);
})
```

Comment: Don't set the socket ref in `app` object. Attaching it to `req` object should be the right way.